# You don't have permission to access / on this server. Heroku redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, heroku, hosting

I have my app hosted at Heroku. I'm trying to use my custom domain, purchased through Ipage. I've changed the DNS record and got all of that sorted out for pointing to Heroku, but I've got a problem that throws the error in the title. I had a developer working on my site before I took over (he accomplished basically nothing). He was writing in PHP and had some very basic content on the site. After I took over and started developing with ROR, I deleted all the files he'd uploaded to the Ipage server in prep to deploy with ROR. I'm newish to programming in general, so not sure if this was wise. Regardless, I found Heroku shortly after and decided to use that for now. Anytime I visit my custom URL, I get the error as above. I'm not sure how to fix it. Most of the answers I've found on this error pertain to the apache server. Please excuse my ignorance, but how can I fix this? I can't see any way to access apache server files in my dashboard. Thanks in advance for any help, and please let me know if I can provide some more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got to tell heroku which domain he should be listening to:

Just run:

```
  $ heroku domains:add your-domain.com
```

See: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains

Good luck

Comment: Ah right you are. I'd added `www.mydomain.com`, but not `mydomain.com`. Working now, thank you.